# SonarQube does not calculate code coverage

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, gradle, sonarqube

I am using postgres sql as  my DB in my springboot application .

My SonarQube is unable to calculate code coverage.can someone please guide me in this

**build.gradle**

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version "${springBootVersion}"
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.15.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
    id 'eclipse'
    id 'jacoco'
    id 'org.sonarqube' version "3.3"
    id 'com.google.cloud.tools.jib' version "${jibVersion}"
}

group = 'com.vsi.postgrestoattentive'

if (!project.hasProperty('buildName')) {
    throw new GradleException("Usage for CLI:" 
        + System.getProperty("line.separator") 
        + "gradlew <taskName> -Dorg.gradle.java.home=<java-home-dir> -PbuildName=<major>.<minor>.<buildNumber> -PgcpProject=<gcloudProject>"
        + System.getProperty("line.separator")
        + "<org.gradle.java.home> - OPTIONAL if available in PATH"
        + System.getProperty("line.separator")
        + "<buildName> - MANDATORY, example 0.1.23")
        + System.getProperty("line.separator")
        + "<gcpProject> - OPTIONAL, project name in GCP";
}

project.ext {
    buildName = project.property('buildName');
}

version = "${project.ext.buildName}"

sourceCompatibility = '1.8'

apply from: 'gradle/sonar.gradle'
apply from: 'gradle/tests.gradle'
apply from: 'gradle/image-build-gcp.gradle'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    
}

dependencies {
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:${springBootVersion}")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator:${springBootVersion}")
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:2.7.0'
    developmentOnly 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.integration:spring-integration-test'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.batch:spring-batch-test:4.3.0'
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa:${springBootVersion}")
    implementation 'org.postgresql:postgresql:42.2.16'
    implementation 'org.springframework.batch:spring-batch-core:4.1.1.RELEASE'
    implementation 'com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310:2.14.1'
    implementation group: 'io.micrometer', name: 'micrometer-registry-datadog', version: '1.7.0'
    
    implementation 'com.google.cloud:libraries-bom:26.3.0'
    implementation 'com.google.cloud:google-cloud-storage:2.16.0'
    
    testImplementation('org.mockito:mockito-core:3.7.7')
    
    //Below 4 dependencies should be commented in local
    implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-kubernetes-client-all:2.0.4'
    implementation 'io.kubernetes:client-java:12.0.0'
    
    implementation("org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-gcp-starter-metrics:${gcpSpringCloudVersion}")
    implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-gcp-logging:1.2.8.RELEASE'

    testImplementation('org.mockito:mockito-core:3.7.7')
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-test'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework:spring-test'
    testImplementation 'org.assertj:assertj-core:3.21.0'

    testImplementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:${springBootVersion}") {
        exclude group: "org.junit.vintage", module: "junit-vintage-engine"
    }
}

bootJar {
    archiveFileName = "${project.name}.${archiveExtension.get()}"
}

springBoot {
    buildInfo()
}


test {
    finalizedBy jacocoTestReport
}

jacoco {
    toolVersion = "0.8.8"
}

jacocoTestReport {
    dependsOn test
}

//: Code to make build check code coverage ratio
project.tasks["bootJar"].dependsOn "jacocoTestReport","jacocoTestCoverageVerification"
```

**tests.gradle**

```
test {

    
    finalizedBy jacocoTestReport
    useJUnitPlatform()
    
    testLogging {
        exceptionFormat = 'full'
    }
    
    afterSuite { desc, result ->
        if (!desc.parent) {
            println "Results: (${result.testCount} tests, ${result.successfulTestCount} successes, ${result.failedTestCount} failures, ${result.skippedTestCount} skipped)"
            boolean skipTests = Boolean.parseBoolean(project.findProperty('SKIP_TESTS') ?: "false")
            if (result.testCount == 0 && !skipTests) {
                throw new IllegalStateException("No tests were found. Failing the build")
            }
        }
    }
    
jacocoTestCoverageVerification {
    dependsOn test
    violationRules {
        rule{
            limit {
            //SMS-28: Since project is in nascent stage setting code coverage ratio limit to 1%
                minimum = 0.5
            }
        }
    }
}

}
```

**sonar.gradle**

```
apply plugin: "org.sonarqube"
apply plugin: 'jacoco'

jacoco {
    toolVersion = "0.8.5"
    reportsDir = file("$buildDir/jacoco")
}


jacocoTestReport {
    reports {
        xml.enabled true
        html.enabled true
        csv.enabled false
    }
}
```

**JenkinsBuildFile**

```
pipeline {

    agent any

    environment {
        // TODO: Remove this
        GIT_BRANCH_LOCAL = sh (
                    script: "echo $GIT_BRANCH | sed -e 's|origin/||g'",
                    returnStdout: true
                ).trim()
        CURRENT_BUILD_DISPLAY="0.1.${BUILD_NUMBER}"
        PROJECT_FOLDER="."
        PROJECT_NAME="xyz"
    
        //Adding default values for env variables that sometimes get erased from GCP Jenkins
        GRADLE_JAVA_HOME="/opt/java/openjdk"
        GCP_SA="abc"
        GCP_PROJECT="efg"
        
        SONAR_JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/java-17-openjdk-amd64"
        SONAR_HOST="http://sonar-sonarqube:9000/sonar"  
        
    }

    stages {
        stage('Clean Workspace') {
            steps {
                echo "Setting current build to ${CURRENT_BUILD_DISPLAY}"
                script {
                    currentBuild.displayName = "${CURRENT_BUILD_DISPLAY}"

                    currentBuild.description = """Branch - ${GIT_BRANCH_LOCAL}"""
                }
                dir("${PROJECT_FOLDER}") {
                    echo "Changed directory to ${PROJECT_FOLDER}"
                    echo 'Cleaning up Work Dir...'
                    // Had to add below chmod command as Jenkins build was failing stating gradlew permission denied
                    sh 'chmod +x gradlew'
                    //gradlew clean means deletion of the build directory.
                    sh './gradlew clean -PbuildName=${CURRENT_BUILD_DISPLAY} -Dorg.gradle.java.home=${GRADLE_JAVA_HOME}'
                    //mkdir -p creates subdirectories
                    //touch creates new empty file
                    sh 'mkdir -p build/libs && touch build/libs/${PROJECT_NAME}-${CURRENT_BUILD_DISPLAY}.jar'
                }
            }
        }

        stage('Tests And Code Quality') {
            steps {
                dir("${PROJECT_FOLDER}") {
                    echo 'Running Tests and SonarQube Analysis'
                     withCredentials([string(credentialsId: 'sonar_key', variable: 'SONAR_KEY')]) {
                        sh '''
                          ./gradlew -i sonarqube -Dorg.gradle.java.home=${SONAR_JAVA_HOME}  \
                                                 -Dsonar.host.url=${SONAR_HOST}  \
                                                 -PbuildName=${CURRENT_BUILD_DISPLAY} \
                                                 -Dsonar.login=$SONAR_KEY \
                                                 -DprojectVersion=${CURRENT_BUILD_DISPLAY}
                        '''
                     }
                    echo 'Ran SonarQube Analysis successfully'
                }
            }
        }       
  

        stage('ECRContainerRegistry') {
            steps {
         withCredentials([file(credentialsId: 'vsi-ops-gcr', variable: 'SECRET_JSON')]) {
                    echo 'Activating gcloud SDK Service Account...'
                    sh 'gcloud auth activate-service-account $GCP_SA --key-file $SECRET_JSON --project=$GCP_PROJECT'
                    sh 'gcloud auth configure-docker'
                    echo 'Activated gcloud SDK Service Account'
                    dir("${PROJECT_FOLDER}") {
                        echo "Pushing image to GCR with tag ${CURRENT_BUILD_DISPLAY}..."
                        sh './gradlew jib -PbuildName=${CURRENT_BUILD_DISPLAY} -PgcpProject=${GCP_PROJECT} -Dorg.gradle.java.home=${GRADLE_JAVA_HOME}'
                        echo "Pushed image to GCR with tag ${CURRENT_BUILD_DISPLAY} successfully"
                    }
                    echo 'Revoking gcloud SDK Service Account...'
                    sh "gcloud auth revoke ${GCP_SA}"
                    echo 'Revoked gcloud SDK Service Account'
                }
            }
        }
    
    }

    post {
        /*
            TODO: use cleanup block
            deleteDir is explicit in failure because always block is run
            before success causing archive failure. Also cleanup block is not
            available in this version on Jenkins ver. 2.164.2
        */
        success {
            dir("${PROJECT_FOLDER}") {
                echo 'Archiving build artifacts...'
                archiveArtifacts artifacts: "build/libs/*.jar, config/**/*", fingerprint: true, onlyIfSuccessful: true
                echo 'Archived build artifacts successfully'
                echo 'Publising Jacoco Reports...'
                jacoco( 
                    execPattern: 'build/jacoco/*.exec',
                    classPattern: 'build/classes',
                    sourcePattern: 'src/main/java',
                    exclusionPattern: 'src/test*'
                )
                echo 'Published Jacoco Reports successfully'
            }
            echo 'Cleaning up workspace...'
            deleteDir()
        }
        failure {
            echo 'Cleaning up workspace...'
            deleteDir()
        }
        aborted {
            echo 'Cleaning up workspace...'
            deleteDir()
        }
    }
}
```

Below is the error which i get in Jenkins console

```
> Task :sonarqube
JaCoCo report task detected, but XML report is not enabled or it was not produced. Coverage for this task will not be reported.
Caching disabled for task ':sonarqube' because:
  Build cache is disabled
Task ':sonarqube' is not up-to-date because:
  Task has not declared any outputs despite executing actions.
JaCoCo report task detected, but XML report is not enabled or it was not produced. Coverage for this task will not be reported.
User cache: /var/jenkins_home/.sonar/cache
Default locale: "en", source code encoding: "UTF-8"
Load global settings
Load global settings (done) | time=101ms
Server id: 4AE86E0C-AX63D7IJvl7jEHIL9nIz
User cache: /var/jenkins_home/.sonar/cache
Load/download plugins
Load plugins index
Load plugins index (done) | time=48ms
Load/download plugins (done) | time=91ms
Process project properties
Process project properties (done) | time=9ms
Execute project builders
Execute project builders (done) | time=1ms

Java "Test" source files AST scan (done) | time=779ms
No "Generated" source files to scan.
Sensor JavaSensor [java] (done) | time=8057ms
Sensor JaCoCo XML Report Importer [jacoco]
'sonar.coverage.jacoco.xmlReportPaths' is not defined. Using default locations: target/site/jacoco/jacoco.xml,target/site/jacoco-it/jacoco.xml,build/reports/jacoco/test/jacocoTestReport.xml
No report imported, no coverage information will be imported by JaCoCo XML Report Importer
Sensor JaCoCo XML Report Importer [jacoco] (done) | time=4ms
```

Can someone please guide me how to resolve this issue of sonar not calculating code coverage

Comment: Do the jacoco report get created? Maybe the location is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

While it could be caused by a number of things, from the logs, it seems likely that it couldn't find the report.

As the first comment says, check to verify that the report is being generated (but not found).  If it is generated, then its likely SQ can't find the XML Jacoco report.

Note the error line, near the end:

> 'sonar.coverage.jacoco.xmlReportPaths' is not defined. Using default locations: target/site/jacoco/jacoco.xml,target/site/jacoco-it/jacoco.xml,build/reports/jacoco/test/jacocoTestReport.xml

An example of defining this location this would be putting this line in `sonar-project.properties`:

> `sonar.coverage.jacoco.xmlReportsPaths=build/reports/jacoco.xml`

It can also be defined directly in a `*.gradle` file:

```
sonarqube {
    properties {
        property "sonar.coverage.jacoco.xmlReportsPaths", "build/reports/jacoco.xml"
    }
}
```