# Disable Integration test case using gradle command in springboot

Tags: spring-boot, gradle, sonarqube

I am using POSTGRES SQL as DB for my springboot application .Sonarqube integration test cases fail as SonarQube is unable to connect to DB.How can i disable my integration test cases using gradlew command during Jenkins build ?

Below is link where i have shown my code in detail [SonarQube does not calculate code coverage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75361474/sonarqube-does-not-calculate-code-coverage)

Answer (score 0):

You would likely have to have some kind of naming convention for the tests you wish to exclude.  Then, you can readily exclude them using something like the following:

In your `build.gradle` file, add:

```
test {
    if (project.hasProperty('excludeTests')) {
        exclude project.property('excludeTests')
    }
}
```

From the command line:

> `gradle test -PexcludeTests=**/Integration*`